# Tomar datos de un mp3 en js

Tags: javascript, mp3

Tengo un campo donde recibe un archivo de sonido mp3, al ser cargado pretendo mostrar información sobre él tales como: foto, título, artista, álbum, género, duración, fecha de creado, peso, velocidad de bits...

Tengo esto, pero no se como obtener la demás información:

```
$("#inputUpload").on("change", function(){

  var itemsLenght = this.files.length;

  for(var i = 0; i < itemsLenght; i++){

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var dv = new jDataView(this.result);

      if (dv.getString(3, dv.byteLength - 128) == 'TAG') {
        var title = dv.getString(30, dv.tell());
        var artist = dv.getString(30, dv.tell());
        var album = dv.getString(30, dv.tell());
        var year = dv.getString(4, dv.tell());

      }else
        console.log('no data');
    }

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.files[i]);
  }

});
```